# Maven project works in eclipse but not from command line

Tags: java, maven, selenium, rest-assured

I have a maven project which mainly has tests. I created it using eclipse. I am able to update maven dependencies from eclipse and able to run all my tests. But, when I try to run those tests from command line using `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`. **It throws an error saying "package com.jayway.restassured does not exist".**

I am new to maven. Any help would be appreciated. The following are additional info about my environment. Thanks.

*Version info:*

```
 Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)
 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 1.6.0_65
 ...
 OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

*pom.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>*******</groupId>
<artifactId>*********</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Groovy because of classpath issue -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <!-- Needs to be the same version that REST Assured depends on -->
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: Beginner post the error: there are a lot of possibilities; are you under firewall?

Comment: What is the command-line you use to run it?

Comment: I am running it from mac using mvn clean install. I am not under any firewall. The following is the error message:

Comment: What's the layout of your project? Does it conform to Maven conventions?

Comment: [ERROR] /Users/ABC/Documents/workspace/ui-qa/src/main/java/com/some/project/qa/common/request/test/CreateRequestTest.java:[3,36] package com.jayway.restassured does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/ABC/Documents/workspace/ui-qa/src/main/java/com/some/project/qa/common/request/test/CreateRequestTest.java:[3,0] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /Users/ABC/Documents/workspace/ui-qa/src/main/java/com/some/project/qa/common/request/test/CreateRequestTest.java:[4,41] package com.jayway.restassured.http does not exist

..........
Hundred error complaining about the same package

Comment: @Vidya - It is a single, not nested under any other project.

Comment: I mean is the source code in *src/main/java*?

Comment: Yes, it is. The project was created through eclipse maven project and it works fine through eclipse. Now, I would like to run all my tests through command line and I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the second dependency with scope test... change to compile

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Groovy because of classpath issue -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```